# memory leak for NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

In xcode instruments i am getting this method memory leak

```
- (void)getDataForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(downloadCompletionBlock)completionHandler
{
    self.expectedLength = 0;
    self.currentLength = 0;
    self.responseData = Nil;
    
    self.contentLengthBlock = nil;
    self.completionBlock = completionHandler;
    
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    
    self.postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
    
    [self.postDataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Hi Shaik, the problem could be with completionHandler and completionBlock when you assign one block to another. Please double-check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A problem in this code snippet is that you are creating a new `NSURLSession` for every request and you never invalidate the sessions. If you call `finishTasksAndInvalidate` after the request is initiated, it will:

- reclaim the memory associated with the `NSURLSession` when the request finishes; and by doing so, it will also
- release the strong reference to the `delegate` object.

Thus:

```
- (void)getDataForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(DownloadCompletionBlock)completionHandler {
    self.expectedLength = 0;
    self.currentLength = 0;
    self.responseData = nil;

    self.contentLengthBlock = nil;
    self.completionBlock = completionHandler;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    self.postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];

    [self.postDataTask resume];
    [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
}
```

If you don't `finishTasksAndInvalidate`, you’ll see leaks like so:

[image]

Calling `finishTasksAndInvalidate` will resolve those issues.

---

There are two other (preferable) alternatives:

- If you are using the delegate solely to process the body of the responses, then you might use the completion-handler block pattern of [`datataskwithurl:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1410330-datataskwithurl) instead, then you might not need to use the delegate protocol at all. You could then use `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` and you don’t need to worry about invalidating the session at all;
- If you really need the delegate (e.g., handling auth challenge requests, detecting redirects, etc.), you can still reconsider whether you need/want to create new session for each request. It’s generally preferable to instantiate a single `NSURLSession`, save a reference to it, and use that single `NSURLSession` (and its associated delegate) for multiple requests. It is more efficient and, again, saves you from needing to invalidate the session after every request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the phrase `delegate: self`. An NSURLSession retains its delegate. Thus you are telling the session to retain this instance (probably a view controller). The view controller cannot go out of existence until you invalidate the session.

The solution is: manage your session correctly. Keep a reference to the session so that you can invalidate it later. Even better, make the delegate a lightweight object, different from the view controller, whose memory you can manage.

Comment: @Rob argh. I'll revise.